# How to delay after every iteration in javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, settimeout, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

How can one delay after the completion of each iteration (or before) in a javascript for loop? Here is my code, but I need to have it 'sleep' for 6 seconds once it sets the color before it moves on to the next one in the list.

```
for (i = 0; i < switchers.length; i++) {
    $('#switchers ol li:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')').css('color', 'green');
}
```

I have tried nesting a setTimeout, but that failed to work, and after searching around google, I decided to ask it here.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a generic function which allows you to loop with a timeout interval.  The code you would normally have in the "for" loop will go inside a function which you pass in as the last argument.

Like this:

```
var loopTimeout = function(i, max, interval, func) {
    if (i >= max) {
        return;
    }

    // Call the function
    func(i);

    i++;

    // "loop"
    setTimeout(function() {
        loopTimeout(i, max, interval, func);
    }, interval);
}
```

- **i** : incrementing variable
- **max** : how many times to loop
- **interval** : timeout interval in ms
- **func** : function to execute each iteration ("i" is passed as the only argument)

**Example usage:**

```
loopTimeout(0, switchers.length, 6000, function(i){
    $('#switchers ol li:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')').css('color', 'green');    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()`.

```
// timeout, in milliseconds to delay each iteration
var actionTimeout = 6000;

$('#switchers ol li').each(function(i, li) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(li).css('color', 'green');
    }, i * actionTimeout);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adDBu/)**

Comment: "That doesn't actually work"... care to actually explain?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Comment: "All functions will see the same value `i`: `switchers.length`". The timeout is the loop iteration multiplied by 6000...

Comment: It will work if you wrap the code inside the loop in an immediately executed function expression: `(function(i){ ... }(i));`. That copies the value for each iteration into the parameter.

Comment: I understand what you mean now @melpomene, your explanation was unclear to me. I've updated my answer and included a better method that addresses the variable scope issues. I would appreciate it if you removed your downvote.